# Heroku toolbelt command requires app-name

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

How do you specify the app you want when you log in to Heroku from the command line?

I was trying to check the logs so when I first logged in I tried:

```
Heroku logs
```

this then told me:

```
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
```

I then tried:

```
heroku --app my-appname
```

but i get:

```
`--app` is not a heroku command.
```

I have tried all combinations.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You still need to include the command:

`heroku logs --app app-name`

You can also use `-a` instead of `--app`:

`heroku logs -a app-name`

Answer (score 49):

Another option is to associate your (git) project to Heroku. From [heroku open - no app specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479668/heroku-open-no-app-specified):

```
$ cd app-dir
$ heroku git:remote -a app-name
$ heroku logs
```

Comment: I've done this per the heroku docs, and it worked briefly, but now I'm getting the same error as rayray and need to specify the "-a app-name" parameter with every heroku command.

Answer (score 25):

**Try this:**

`heroku git:remote -a [app_name]`

This should allow you to call commands without having to specify which app you want them to be called on.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding `--app app-name` after you sentence.

Example: `$ heroku domains:add your-domain --app app-name`

Answer (score 2):

Heroku CLI automatically detects the app name by scanning the git remotes for the current working copy.

If you're not in the app's local git clone, you need to specify the app name:

```
heroku logs --app app-name
```

or

```
heroku logs -a app-name
```

or by specifying the remote name:

```
heroku logs --remote production
```

You can reference this part of the Heroku documentation:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands

Answer (score 0):

From my tests the Heroku CLI will infer the app from the current **Git *remote***.

So to change to the "**test**" app:

```
git config heroku.remote test
```

And to come back to the default "**heroku**" application, which is probably your production app:

```
git config heroku.remote heroku
```

Not sure this is a good idea though...

Answer (score -1):

For future solution seekers-

The error says a possible solution.

> Run this command from an app folder

`cd` to the app directory root, then run your desired command.