# heroku open - no app specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've just created a simple Rails app using

```
rails new myapp
```

then created the heroku stack using:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

But when I try opening the app on Heroku using:

```
heroku open
```

I get:

```
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
```

And this:

```
$ heroku open --app myapp
```

gives me this:

```
 !    App not found
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You no longer have to specify the cedar stack, it is the default now

Comment: Make sure to scroll down past the first couple answers. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24816347/199712) is the best.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you have an existing app on Heroku and you are getting this no app specified message, you can correct it by running this on your local terminal:

`heroku git:remote -a MyHerokuAppName`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

I use auto-deploys from a git branch. For an unrelated reason I needed to form a new repo. This was exactly what I needed to fix that.

Also, when I wanted to interact with heroku from a different machine (actually a cloud9 dev environment), this simple command let me connect and work with heroku.

Answer (score 26):

Heroku by default is not creating app with your directory name, so when you do

```
heroku create --stack cedar
Creating calm-bayou-3229... done, stack is cedar
http://calm-bayou-3229.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:calm-bayou-3229.git
```

it is creating application named 'calm-bayou-3229'
And you can do

```
heroku open --app calm-bayou-3229
Opening http://calm-bayou-3229.herokuapp.com/
```

You can always list your apps with:

```
heroku apps
```

Answer (score 20):

Another approach to solving the issue is to take a broad understanding of what the .git/config file associated with the heroku app is doing and make the necessary tweaks.

1.Open `.git/config` from your heroku project's root.

Your git config file may look something like this, especially if you are juggling a couple heroku accounts on your machine.

`git@heroku.{heroku.account}` shows up instead of `git@heroku.com` because of the configuration in your `~/.ssh/config` file.  The reference to `heroku-app-8396.git` should be updated to match your heroku project name. Each heroku account you have should have an entry in the `~/.ssh/config` file.  Obviously, the heroku account that this heroku project is associated with should show up in your `.git/config` file.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@heroku.heroku.account:heroku-app-8396.git
[remote "heroku"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
    url = git@heroku.heroku.account:heroku-app-8396.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[heroku]
  account = heroku.account
```

2.When I run `git pull heroku master`, all seems to run well.

3.When I run `heroku logs`, I get an error message:

```
$ heroku ps
!    No app specified.
!    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

Why?

As far as I can tell, the `heroku` command doesn't seem to know what to do with the `{heroku.account}` references.  If we change those references to `com` (which is the default value when you are not using the 'accounts' heroku plugin), the `heroku` commands work once again, but now our `git` calls are saying there is a different problem:

```
$ git pull heroku master

 !  Your key with fingerprint d6:1b:4c:48:8c:52:d4:d6:f8:32:aa:1a:e7:0e:a2:a1 is not authorized to access smooth-robot-8396.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

One way to resolve this is to define a remote for `git` and a remote for `heroku` and then tell `heroku` which remote to use.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@heroku.heroku.account:heroku-app-8396.git
[remote "heroku"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
    url = git@heroku.heroku.account:heroku-app-8396.git
[remote "heroku-app"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
    url = git@heroku.com:heroku-app-8396.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[heroku]
    remote = heroku-app
    account = heroku.account
```

I like to explicitly specify the remote when I'm pushing content to a remote, so the `heroku` remote is for that, even though this configuration also accommodates pushing/pulling using the default (e.g., `git push`).  I create a new remote 'heroku-app' and add `remote = heroku-app` to tell `heroku` to use a remote that doesn't include the heroku account in the URI.

Now I can run my `git` and `heroku` commands as I want to.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your ~/.ssh/config? Also an example of how you push to heroku would be helpful. I tried following your example but was unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is an amazing answer!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, All I had to do was cd to project dir instead of running commands from model folder in the project dir.

Answer (score 2):

> This crazy thing worked for me:

If you have the app's git repo copy on you local machine then `cd` to that location and **that's it**!!

You will be able to use the app. You can verify this by commands like: `heroku logs -n 1500`